# std::sort - indirection requires pointer operand

Tags: c++, c++14, clang++

I want to sort a vector of Sprite objects

```
std::function<bool(const Sprite&,const Sprite&)> fn;
fn = [](auto&& a, auto&& b) ->bool { return a.pos.x > b.pos.x; };
std::sort(sprites.begin(), sprites.end(), fn);
```

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/predefined_ops.h:123:31: fatal error:
indirection requires pointer operand ('Sprite' invalid)
{ return bool(_M_comp(*__it1, *__it2)); }
```

But if I inline the sorting function there is no error. What is the problem?

I'm using clang version 3.7.0 but the error seems not to appear in gcc.

Comment: [Seems to work for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebec9531002dfe35) (modulo the fact that polymorphic lambdas are a C++14 feature)

Comment: Yes I'm using c++14. It seems like the problem is in clang since the code compiles using gcc. I will update my question.

Comment: @AnonymousEntity - I'm confused. I've tried the example written by milleniumbug and work; but if I change the compiler with clang++, give your error; compiling with clang++ but adding `-stdlib=lib++`, the error disappear. So I suppose it's a problem between clang++ and stdlibc++. Trying in my debian (g++ 4.9.2 and clang++ 3.5.0) I have non compilation error at all (g++ and clang++ with or without libc++). So I suppose the problem started from clang++ 3.6 or 3.7.

Comment: Can anyone find a workaround for making the code bit work without changing compiler / libs?

Comment: @AnonymousEntity - a workaround could be avoid `std::function`, avoid the lambda function, define a comparer function (a good old style function) like `bool compS (const Sprite & a, const Sprite & b) { return a.pos.x > b.pos.x; }` and use it invoking `std::sort` (`std::sort(sprites.begin(), sprites.end(), compS)`)

Comment: Does `auto&&` replaced with `auto&` change the error?  Replaced with `Sprite const&`?

Comment: @Yakk - no; I've tried modifing in coliru the milleniumbug's example using `auto const &` or `Sprite const &` but the compiler error remain. Coliru use clang++ 3.8.

Comment: Because _somebody_ has to mention it..: Storing a lambda into a `std::function` should be a last resort; doing it at local scope like this is pure, silly pessimization.

Comment: @ildjarn Right. In my code it's used as a "strategy pattern" for the different layers in a scene to sort sprites. For example, the UI layer wants to sort with a different algorithm than the battlefield, and so on.

Comment: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24115